# Sonarqube: cross-file custom java rule?

Tags: java, sonarqube

We're looking to implement a custom rule that would involve having to navigate the syntax tree across different files. Something like:

ClassA --> private ClassB field --> ClassB --> private ClassC field --> ClassC ...

However, I'm not sure if there is a possibility of doing this. I looked at the example repository as well as the existing sonar checks that are written but most (if not all) seem to be limited to file-scope. I was wondering if there is a way to approach this?

I've currently tried fetching the declaration variable from the class' symbol type, like so:

```
public void visitNode(final Tree tree) {
    final ClassTree clazz = (ClassTree) tree;

    final VariableTree memberField = tree.members().get(0);
    final JavaSymbol memberClassSymbol = (JavaSymbol) memberField.symbol().type().symbol();
    final ClassTree memberClass = memberClassSymbol.declaration();
}
```

However, this field is null. Seems to be in every case I've tried. Is there a different way to approach this task with a custom sonar extension?

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to precise exactly what you want to detect, because semantic API could help you out here.

Comment: @benzonico Thanks for the reply. In our case we are trying to implement a rule to help with serialization - classes that are marked as serialize (and thus don't show up as warnings in IDEs or as existing rules) in serializable classes that aren't actually serializable for other reasons. So for example in ClassA we have two fields: ClassB and MyBean. MyBean contains ClassD. In our case, we want to be able to scan classA and flag classB with this rule, and then continue scanning the other fields (MyBean) for others that would violate it. In this case, ClassD would then be flagged.

Comment: isn't this rule covering your need ? https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS1948

Comment: Not exactly - the idea is there but unfortauntely we've run into cases where in our code (and in third party libraries) classes that are marked as serializable (and thus don't trigger that rule) aren't actually - we get error when trying to serialize the session. What we're trying to implement is more of an extension to that rule to flag offending classes that we're aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible at *syntax* level : the analysis is done file by file.

Once a file is analyzed, syntax tree is dropped and analysis goes to the next file. As there is no guarantee about the order in which the files are analyzed you also can't store some syntax nodes for later use.

However, using semantic analysis, which analyze bytecode, depending on what you want to achieve you can rely on semantic API and detect that class B has a field of type C (using symbols and types) etc.

Comment: After re-reviewing this issue I see what you mean via semantic analysis - we don't have access to the trees but can use symbolScope() and so on "traverse" the tree for what we require. Thanks.

Comment: Recorded but not displayed, as I've never posted before :( Sorry haha.